# asp.net pick up the image from css root folder

Tags: css, asp.net

I write this for pick up image from my root folder:

```
#sidebar h2 {
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 0 2px 30px;
background: url(~/images/img05.gif) no-repeat left bottom;
border-bottom: 2px solid #4A3903;
}
```

my image in the root folder ,but image not show!

Comment: ideally `~` it should works because it means from root. try to put the image path in ` " "` `background: url("~/images/img05.gif") no-repeat left bottom;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
background: url('../images/img05.gif') no-repeat left bottom;
```

Comment: @user3924437: u are welcome :),did this answer solved your problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Ideally `~` it should works because it means to pick from `root`. you are missing quote in image path so may be the image is not displaying.

```
#sidebar h2 {
margin: 0;
padding: 20px 0 2px 30px;
background: url("~/images/img05.gif") no-repeat left bottom;
border-bottom: 2px solid #4A3903;
}
```